# Possible conditional probability problem

Tags: probability

I'm trying to understand the following question:

> Consider that a consumer buys with probability p, only one of three items A, B, C. 
>   If it buys, he will choose A, B or C of equiprobable manner. 
>   He hasn't bought neither A nor B. What is the probability that he buys C?

For me, the result is only the probability of the consumer buy the product, because i know that he hasn't bought neither A nor B. but i'm not sure, because i didn't had used any conditional probability and i think it's necessary to consider that here. 
Well i would like to know if my reasoning is correct.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to not buy products A or B.  You can buy product C, or you can not buy any product at all.

Let event $C$ mean product C is bought. $\mathsf P(C)= \tfrac 1 3 p$

Let event $D$ mean one of the products is bought. $\mathsf P(D)=p$

Thus $C\subset D$.

You want to find, using conditional probability:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(C\mid C\cup D^c)
& = \frac {\mathsf P(C \cap (C\cup D^c))}{\mathsf P(C\cup D^c)}
\\[1ex]
& = \frac{\mathsf P(C)}{\mathsf P(C)+\mathsf P(D^c)}
\end{align}$$

Can you finish this?

Comment: Yes, i can finish. Thanks for the response.